# Consume API in AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

What is the best way to consume an API in the AdonisJS controller?

It is possible to use axios and send the data to the view?

```
'use strict'

const axios = require('axios')

class PostController {

  index({ view }) {

    const api = axios.get()...

    return view.render('welcome', { name, text })


  }

}

module.exports = PostController
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @GersonLCSJunior said, there is no module for that.

Adonis (e.g. [vow package](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-vow)) uses the [`superagent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) library for http requests. Personally, I don't like this library.

If you're using Axios, don't forget to use `await` operator.
Like:

```js
const axios = use('axios');
const querystring = use('querystring'); // https://github.com/axios/axios#nodejs

const req = await axios.post(
   'https://mywebsite/',
    querystring.stringify({
     message: 'hello',
    })
);
console.info(req)
```

Answer (score 4):

AdonisJS doesn't have any built-in module to send requests, so you're free to use whatever library you want. Axios should work fine.